# Android Intent.ACTION_SEND from Internal Storage with Content Provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, internal-storage, share-intent, android-internal-storage

I am saving a file on internal storage. It is just a .txt file with some information about objects:

```
    FileOutputStream outputStream;
    String filename = "file.txt";

    File cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
    File outFile = new File(cacheDir, filename);
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile.getAbsolutePath());
    outputStream.write(myString.getBytes());
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
```

Then I am creating a "shareIntent" to share this file:

```
    Uri notificationUri = Uri.parse("content://com.package.example/file.txt");
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, notificationUri);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, context.getResources().getText(R.string.chooser)));
```

The chosen app now needs access to the private file so I created a Content provider. I just changed the openFile method:

```
@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File privateFile = new File(getContext().getCacheDir(), uri.getPath());
    return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(privateFile, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
}
```

The manifest:

```
<provider
        android:name=".ShareContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.package.example"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="true">
    </provider>
```

When opening the Mail App to share the file it says, that it could not attach the file because it only has 0 Bytes. Sharing it via Bluetooth also failed. But I can read out the `privateFile` in the Content Provider, so it exists and it has content. What is the problem?

Comment: is `query()` method called in your custom `ContentProvider`?

Comment: Yes is called 3 times before openFile. First argument is always: content://com.package.example/file.txt

Comment: and the projection / columns are: _display_name and _size ? BTW why not to use `android.support.v4.content.FileProvider`?

Comment: Yes they are in the second argument. I only found ContentProvider when searching this. But I'll take a look at FileProvider now too.

Comment: but if you still want your custom `ContentProvider` see `android.provider.OpenableColumns`

Comment: Try to get it running with `ContentProvider` as it is much more flexible then `FilePrivider`.

Comment: `they are in the second argument. ` And.. do you provide the requested info?

Comment: just use a `MatrixCursor` if you dont know what to return from `query` method

Comment: What do you mean with flexible? All I need is the access to the private file.

Comment: `flexible? All I need is the access to the private file`. Maybe today only. But later... With FileProvider you only can serve files from predetermined directories. Predetermind by Google. Not by you.

Comment: `opening the Mail App to share the file`. Which one? There mostly are  more on a system. Try others too.

Comment: Okay then I try that out again. I only have one on the device. But sending with bluetooth failed too, saying it cannot find the file.

Comment: To encourange you: your code looks ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for pskink. FileProvider worked perfectly:

Gradle dependency:

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'`

Manifest:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.package.example"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

file_paths.xml in XML folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <cache-path name="cache" path="/" />
</paths>
```

Sharing Intent:

```
    File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), filename);

    Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.package.example", file);

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, context.getResources().getText(R.string.chooser)));
```

Comment: You may also need to add this to the intent:

shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);